# C++ Beginner. cout not outputting string into console?

Tags: c++

I am following along with Bjarne Stroustrup's book "Programming: Principles and practice using C++", and I am running into a problem that I am struggling to solve (I've spent an hour+ trying to figure it out on my own with 0 progress).

He suggests using his custom header file, which I have copy and pasted into a new header file:

http://stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h

Now, I am to write a simple hello_world program that outputs a `"Hello, world."` string in the console.

However, when I run the program, all it says is:

```
"Press any key to continue..."
```

With no other strings output.

This is the program (my code is identical to the books):

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {

    cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TheDude I'm not getting any compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Plain code dump without any further explanation, but upvoted. That's certainly a great resource for beginners :-P ...

Comment: This wouldn't even compile, because there's no `keep_window_open` function in the standard library.

Comment: @Olaf, I didn't write it.  Remy edited my post and put it in there.  It is probably something that is available to the OP, since he had it in his code.